# Troubleshooting Issues with php8.0-opcache configuration

Tags: apt

I am currently facing difficulties while trying to configure the 'php8.0-opcache' package on my system. The specific error I am encountering is as follows:

[image: error-screenshot]

This situation is causing inconveniences on my system, and I am seeking guidance on how to resolve these dependency issues. If anyone could provide specific guidance or suggestions on how to address this error, I would greatly appreciate it.

Additional information about the environment:

```
apt install php8.0 libapache2-mod-php8.0
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Copy the text and paste it into your question.